# Templatizer - How to render multiple times same template, Polymer 2.x

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

In Polymer 1.x I was used to write a templatize code like this:

```
renderTemplate(query, properties) {
  let element = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(query);
  this.templatize(element);
  var instance = this.stamp(properties);
  return instance;
}
```

which worked well. But in Polymer 2.x there is a new error message `A <template> can only be templatized once`. Well it doesn't make sense, because I have 1 template which I want to redistribute multiple times with different properties.

I am giving here an example of how is my code

I have `#template1` and `#template2`
I want to render `#template1` then `#template2` then `#template1`.

In steps how I render templates:

1) templatize `#template1`

2) stamp properties

3) templatize `#template2`

4) stamp properties

5 a) templatize `#template1` => ERROR

5 b) skip templatize and stamp properties => `#template2` is rendered....

How am i able to make this possible? calling `stamp()` after rendering `#template2` will result in another `#template2` render. I want `#template1`, but I can't `templatize #template1` because it has been already templatized.  And `stamp` is always "binded" to last templatized element.

Am I doing something wrong? I do really hate Polymer because of it's bad documentation and hard to google something usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround which is propably not the best solution but it works. I tried to search in source code for some solutions but there wasn't anything usefull except the one property called `__templatizeOwner`. This property is set to all templatized elements. Removing this property from an element is the way.

```
renderTemplate(query, properties) {
  let element = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(query);
  if(element.__templatizeOwner) {
    element.__templatizeOwner = null;
  }
  this.templatize(element);
  var instance = this.stamp(properties);
  return instance;
}
```

I am not sure what side effects this might have (more memory usage or something) but this is the only way I was able to find out.